# What is a tensor product

Tags: tensor-products, characters

I know this question has already been answered many times elsewhere. I now formally the definition of a tensor product, however I do not get the point of it: why is it used ans how to think of it?

To be a bit more precise, I bumped into a text considering $X=(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and stating that the characters of $X$ are exactly the quadratic characters of $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Why is that so? (I guess I have no idea because I do not understand how to compute with such tensor products, define characters, etc.)

Comment: What properties does a character of $X$ have?

Comment: @Somos Multiplicativity I guess. At least as a character on Z\NZ^\times, but what is the relation with the tensor product?

Comment: Actually, I mean what is your definition of a character of a group? And then how do you apply that to the tensor product $X$ using your definition of tensor product.

Comment: The homomorphisms from a tensor product $A\otimes B$ to $C$ are essentially the bilinear maps from $A\times B$ to $C$.